# Slow Docker Container on GCP running Python AI/ML Workloads

Tags: docker, centos7, google-cloud-platform, python

Looking for advice on how to diagnose high system/kernel space load.

**Setup**

- Docker CE on CentOS 7 (no SELinux)
- Containerized Python based AI/ML workload.
- Python multi-processing is in use with ((n/2)-2) pool workers
- n => cpu/vcpu cores (1 hyper-thread)

**General Issue**

- On Bare metal container from our docker image runs as expected.
- On GCP container based on same image runs slow, 3-4 times slow.
- AI Pipelines that originally took 2 days now taking 4/5 days.

**Specific Issue**

- GCP top -> high system/kernel space load (30-50).
- Bare-metal(BM) top -> low system load (1-10).
- BM Individual Processes at most 100-120 %CPU.
- GCP individual processes 300-500 %CPU.
- BM Load Average 11.85, 32.87, 19.43
- GCP LA 43.82, 32.87, 19.43

**What we Tried**

- Set full privileged=true on docker run
- Doubled the vCPU on GCP (32->64)
- Used C2 (Compute Intensive) machine type.

Since I'm having no clue on how to diagnose this top-down thus also tried perf to see what is happening in the kernel/system space, following is the output from both systems.

**GCP VM 'perf trace'**

```
Summary of events:    

python (2551), 6580977 events, 3.9%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  sched_yield      3232286 50396.443     0.002     0.016    68.851      0.69%    
  futex              58139 23715.636     0.001     0.408 21989.789     92.73%    
  brk                 1643   312.000     0.002     0.190    19.195     13.42%    
  close                  5    35.710     3.630     7.142    18.245     39.07%    
  openat                 4    12.764     2.710     3.191     3.767      7.16%    
  write                165     9.681     0.003     0.059     6.496     66.95%    
  ioctl                 85     0.605     0.002     0.007     0.028      9.58%    
  lseek                182     0.460     0.002     0.003     0.004      1.70%    
  read                  10     0.104     0.003     0.010     0.019     15.84%    
  fstat                  4     0.030     0.006     0.007     0.008      6.21%    

python (2847), 10240661 events, 6.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex               2909 269175.495     0.001    92.532 21907.964     13.70%    
  sched_yield      5119771 63387.192     0.002     0.012    98.500      0.60%    

ython (2848), 10952416 events, 6.4%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex               2944 269333.572     0.001    91.486 21908.135     13.70%    
  sched_yield      5475608 62191.735     0.002     0.011    54.373      0.56%    

python (2849), 10095381 events, 5.9%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex               2869 269495.562     0.001    93.934 21907.785     13.69%    
  sched_yield      5046875 63404.111     0.002     0.013    69.027      0.53%    

python (2850), 10871629 events, 6.4%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex               3379 269541.688     0.001    79.770 21908.129     13.71%    
  sched_yield      5434655 61881.631     0.002     0.011    92.192      0.66%    

python (2851), 10471715 events, 6.2%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex               3267 269665.818     0.001    82.542 21908.306     13.70%    
  sched_yield      5234762 62440.899     0.002     0.012    70.764      0.59%    

python (2852), 11048544 events, 6.5%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex               3075 269845.352     0.001    87.755 21908.402     13.69%    
  sched_yield      5523384 61269.561     0.002     0.011    77.207      0.58%    

python (2853), 10802913 events, 6.4%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex               3411 269995.415     0.001    79.154 21907.717     13.70%    
  sched_yield      5400121 61586.390     0.000     0.011    63.498      0.63%    

python (2854), 10580227 events, 6.2%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex               3237 270029.557     0.001    83.420 21907.737     13.69%    
  sched_yield      5289038 62372.649     0.002     0.012    50.329      0.56%    


python (2855), 11269016 events, 6.6%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex               3309 270088.861     0.001    81.623 21908.143     13.69%    
  sched_yield      5633482 61010.474     0.002     0.011    59.756      0.54%    

python (2856), 11194619 events, 6.6%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex               3355 270348.851     0.001    80.581 21917.988     13.68%    
  sched_yield      5596230 61122.634     0.002     0.011    52.892      0.60%    

python (2857), 11236749 events, 6.6%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex               2559 273140.199     0.001   106.737 21916.745     13.53%    
  sched_yield      5618107 61171.202     0.002     0.011    74.198      0.59%    

python (2858), 10328444 events, 6.1%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex               2759 270424.625     0.001    98.015 21916.130     13.66%    
  sched_yield      5163708 62490.561     0.002     0.012    95.956      0.65%    


python (2859), 11507002 events, 6.8%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex               3065 270481.725     0.001    88.249 21910.849     13.67%    
  sched_yield      5752618 60412.759     0.002     0.011    96.043      0.69%    


python (2860), 11013249 events, 6.5%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex               3254 270691.944     0.001    83.187 21912.965     13.67%    
  sched_yield      5505249 60965.211     0.002     0.011    69.026      0.62%    


python (2861), 11793518 events, 6.9%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex               2851 270700.999     0.001    94.949 21911.187     13.66%    
  sched_yield      5896062 60165.571     0.002     0.010    69.030      0.69%    

python (2862), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (2863), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (2864), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (2865), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%
```

**TOP (GCP VM)**

```
top - 11:09:17 up 3 min,  1 user,  load average: 35.10, 12.57, 4.53    
Tasks: 337 total,  15 running, 322 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie    
%Cpu(s): 52.0 us, 43.1 sy,  0.0 ni,  4.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st    
GiB Mem :     28.1 total,     24.3 free,      3.3 used,      0.6 buff/cache    
GiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.     24.5 avail Mem     
    
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                            
 2501 root      20   0 2955128 169656   7612 R 380.5  0.6   3:24.55 python                                             
 2502 root      20   0 2959472 176016   7612 R 307.6  0.6   3:17.58 python                                             
 2495 root      20   0 2959088 176400   7608 R 288.4  0.6   3:35.93 python                                             
 2496 root      20   0 2933612 151452   7600 R 262.9  0.5   3:27.08 python                                             
 2494 root      20   0 2933356 153248   7604 R 253.3  0.5   3:22.47 python                                             
 2489 root      20   0 2949156 166916   7652 R 250.7  0.6   3:13.78 python                                             
 2500 root      20   0 2941704 153928   7632 R 225.5  0.5   3:24.54 python                                             
 2499 root      20   0 2950132 164576   7620 R 210.6  0.6   3:14.79 python                                             
 2493 root      20   0 2936304 151568   7608 R 177.2  0.5   3:28.18 python                                             
 2490 root      20   0 2949248 169748   7596 R 170.9  0.6   3:16.57 python                                             
 2497 root      20   0 2932684 156128   7600 R 167.9  0.5   3:13.12 python                                             
 2491 root      20   0 2942860 165400   7608 R 149.0  0.6   3:17.05 python                                             
 2492 root      20   0 2947632 163008   7604 R 117.2  0.6   3:20.01 python                                             
 2498 root      20   0 2935784 153348   7600 R  76.2  0.5   3:14.54 python                                             
 2943 root      20   0  162376   2560   1588 R   0.7  0.0   0:00.08 top                                                
    1 root      20   0  191028   4024   2592 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.68 systemd
```

**Bare Metal 'perf trace'**

```
Summary of events:    

python (113694), 88758 events, 2.7%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex               3174 13767.708     0.001     4.338 13745.177     99.84%    
  sched_yield        39353   130.937     0.002     0.003     3.972      3.91%    
  brk                 1132    91.005     0.002     0.080     4.163     15.54%    
  write                101     1.928     0.002     0.019     0.673     34.59%    
  lseek                110     0.310     0.001     0.003     0.032     12.49%    
  openat                 2     0.234     0.112     0.117     0.122      4.49%    
  ioctl                 36     0.162     0.002     0.005     0.010      7.15%    
  read                   6     0.033     0.003     0.005     0.008     16.09%    
  fstat                  2     0.008     0.004     0.004     0.004      2.01%    
  close                  3     0.007     0.002     0.002     0.003      5.55%    


python (114304), 3210496 events, 97.3%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex               3640 97379.595     0.000    26.753 13930.078     20.68%    
  sched_yield      1599811  3995.576     0.001     0.002    15.957      0.91%    


python (114305), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114306), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114307), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114308), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114309), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114310), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114311), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114312), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114313), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114314), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114315), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114316), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114317), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114318), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114319), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114320), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114321), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114322), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114323), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114324), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114325), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114326), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114327), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114328), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114329), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114330), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114331), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114332), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114333), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114334), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114335), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114336), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114337), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114338), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114339), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114340), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%    


python (114341), 1 events, 0.0%    

  syscall            calls    total       min       avg       max      stddev    
                              (msec)    (msec)    (msec)    (msec)        (%)    
  --------------- -------- --------- --------- --------- ---------     ------    
  futex                  1     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000      0.00%
```

Apparently too many events in GCP, specifically `futex` and `sched_yield`, both clearly taking lot of time in the system space.

Thanks

Comment: sched_yield just means the task is switched for another, long running futex calls can be the consequence of memory contention. Maybe GCP is using a custom allocator. Anyway you can try `perf top` and `vmstat` to get another look. Or maybe they use other kernel options and have enabled another kind of futexes which don't particularly work well with your load. Or it is memory accounting options in the container.

Comment: @Gerrit, thanks for your attention, added top from GCP VM, I've hit the max character limit for text, so had to remove some top output, all of which was '0' usage.

Comment: Hmmm. I wonder. AI uses a lot of random numbers probably. Could the processes be waiting on new randomness?

Comment: let me explore that path, will report back, thanks.

Comment: vmstat output
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
45  0      0 25672764   2192 647520    0    0    31     1  558 1611 29 24 46  0  0

Comment: Perhaps an `strace -f -p pid` of one of the python processes would clarify things.

Comment: @Gerrit I could not spot a select on u/random, still mounted host urandom to container random device, no difference, besides in the bare metal environment containers are working fine without urandom, so it should be safe to conclude that entropy is probably not the cause.

Comment: I've added the strace output in chat to preserve structure (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128466/discussion-between-ravi-and-gerrit).

Comment: will update after the analysis of 'strace -f -p pid' output... 10 million lines to skim through